# Python: Module Error with pprint, no error with print

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this function that creates a dictionary called `a()` and takes parameters `params`. I want to print that dictionary, so I used pprint:

```
dict=a(params)
pprint(dict)
```

pprint gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

but print works fine!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

How did you import `pprint`? If you didn't specify what to import from `pprint` you need to use the module name when calling.

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(...)
```

Or you can import a specific method.

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(...)
```